# DelayedJobAdapter fails with EOFError: end of file reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, office365

I have set up a mailer with SMTP through Office 365, which works perfectly fine without queuing adapter. However, when I start queuing jobs, I get:

```
Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=2)
FAILED (5 prior attempts) with EOFError: end of file reached
```

Not sure if it matters, but I am running my server through SSL.

Here is my config:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.office365.com',
port:                 587,
user_name:            ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
password:             ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
authentication:       :login,
enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

The controller:

```
SendEmailJob.set(wait: 5.seconds).perform_later
```

Here is what is see in the delayed_jobs sqlite3 table:

```
8|0|5|--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper
job_data:
  job_class: ActionMailer::DeliveryJob
  job_id: 2fb5924b-c1b5-4383-80cb-0c4b9c4300ce
  queue_name: mailers
  arguments:
  - UserMailer
  - welcome_email
  - deliver_now
|end of file reached
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:174:in `sysread_nonblock'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:174:in `read_nonblock'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:929:in `recv_response'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:915:in `block in getok'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:939:in `critical'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:913:in `getok'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:907:in `quit'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:613:in `do_finish'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:522:in `ensure in start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:522:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:543:in `block in deliver_mail'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:541:in `deliver_mail'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `deliver'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/delivery_job.rb:10:in `perform'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/execution.rb:32:in `block in perform_now'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:338:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `instance_exec'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `block in make_lambda'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:337:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:337:in `block in simple'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_perform_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/execution.rb:31:in `perform_now'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/execution.rb:21:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activejob-4.2.0/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb:34:in `perform'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:94:in `block in invoke_job'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:91:in `invoke_job'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:204:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:204:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:203:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:280:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:280:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:187:in `block in work_off'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `times'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `work_off'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:150:in `block (4 levels) in start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:149:in `block (3 levels) in start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:148:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:147:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:147:in `block in start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:146:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'|2015-02-03 01:01:39.509092||||mailers|2015-02-03 00:44:09.243109|2015-02-03 00:51:09.516624
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I simply forgot to set up env variables for my Office365 account. They were set up in apache2 envvars, but when launching rake jobs:run they should have been set up separately.

I managed to identify this when I tried to send through Google. And Google did said that SMTP authentication failed. It's really weird that with Office365 it complains with EOFError.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Gmail SMTP. Adding

```
domain: 'mydomain.com'
```

to the SMTP configuration fixed it for me.